# check specific package name running in android foreground

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on kiosk `xamarin.android` app.
I need to know what is my current foreground app `(PackageName)`.

tried few samples but no use.

--sample 1

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)BaseContext.GetSystemService(ActivityService);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = activityManager.RunningAppProcesses.ToList();
            foreach (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo in runningProcesses)
            {
                if (processInfo.Importance == Android.App.Importance.Foreground)
                {
                    foreach (String activeProcess in processInfo.PkgList)
                    {
                        if (activeProcess.Equals(_context.PackageName))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

--sample 2--

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
var packageName = activityManager.RunningAppProcesses;
```

--sample 3--

```
var am = _context.GetSystemService(ActivityService).JavaCast<ActivityManager>();
IList<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.GetRunningTasks(5);
var componentInfo = taskInfo[0].TopActivity;
```

I call those codes in `OnPause()`, but all of these returns only my task `(my package name)`.

I have followed this example also
[find application running in foreground from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591116/find-application-running-in-foreground-from-service)

I'm very glad if anyone can give me at least a reason.

Comment: What's your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: Android Oreo 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer

[Android 5.1.1 and above - getRunningAppProcesses() returns my application package only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag)

```
UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager)this.getSystemService("usagestats");
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 1000*1000, time);
    if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
        SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
        }
        if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
            currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
        }
    }
```