# How to know which app is in foreground programmatically?

Tags: android

Let's say my android application has a foreground service which is intended to show currently running application name in the notification.

Given that, Is there any way I can get the name of the application that is running in the foreground currently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find application running in foreground from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591116/find-application-running-in-foreground-from-service)

Comment: @greeble31 The permission mentioned in the link is deprecated.